# RxJava - How to return the last 2 items from a Flowable for a new Observer

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

I have a `Flowable<String>` that returns the `LATEST` set of `String`. This is part of a library class. Is there a way for me to return the last 2 `strings` when a new observer subscribes to this `Flowable`.

I can make changes to the `Flowable` to be setup with a `BUFFER` strategy as well but that would send a whole bunch of elements back to the Observer. What would be a good way to send back 2 previous elements here?

```
private fun observeFlowable() : Flowable<String> {
  observer().toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
}


// The listener

private fun observeFlowable() {
    observeFlowable().buffer(2).doSomething()
}
```

When the observer starts listening, the `buffer(2)` never gets called as `observeFlowable()`  if it comes in late will never fire.

Comment: It would help if you code add a little code snippet to better demonstrate what you have and what you need, so other people can provide a solution based on your code

Comment: Thanks! I added code. Let me know if you want me to add more.